# sum value from row php

Tags: php, html

how to correct my output, this first is what I want

[image]

and this is what it did

[image]

this is my code:

```
<?php for( $i = 0 ; $i<count($db_charge);$i++) { ?>
<tBody id="tbl_rec">
   <tr>
      <td><?php
         $date_date = $db_charge[$i]['dDate'];
         echo $new_date = date('D-j-F-Y H:i' , strtotime($date_date)); ?></td>
      <td><?php
         echo $db_charge[$i]['iBalance'];
            
             ?></td>
      <td> <?php 
         $iBal +=  $db_charge[$i]['iBalance'];
         echo $iBal; 
         
           ?>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tBody>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hi Obelias, you might include what values you have in `$db_charge`. Also it looks like your expected result is quite different (i.e. you're not expecting a date at all?) - have you tried modifying the code inside the `<td>` elements to output something different?

Comment: It seems you want to sum the values as you go along, but the problem is you'd be trying to use values which haven't been retrieved from the array yet. You need to first process the array in reverse order to calculate the cumulative totals, add the total for each row as a new property to each array item and then go back and output the array in the normal order.

Comment: How would you describe, in words, what output you need? Do you just want it in reverse order? Do you actually want to show the numbers in parentheses, or is that just to explain where your totals have come from? Is the "3000" on the first line a typo?